# Como saber el id de un elemento mediante una clase en funcion si el estilo "display2 paso de none a block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hola amigos tengo un monton de elementos dinamicos que se tienen la misma clase, y estos se muestran o no mediante el estilo display block, me gustaria saber en base al cambio del estilo el id de dicho elemento.

Comment: Podrías mostrar tu código?

Comment: $downElem.find('.mascaras:eq(' + val + ')').css({display: 'block'});
        
he intentado con esto

Comment: Debes poner el código completo para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: He marcado la pregunta como posible duplicado ya que no muestra nada de código y el concepto es el mismo, solo que cambiando el evento. En tu caso debería ser un evento `change` en vez de `click`.

Answer (score 0):

Como que no compartes tu código tuve que inventarlo: tengo 10 div, que tienen `display:block`. Los pares sin embargo, tienen `display: none`.

Para saber el valor de `display` para un div `d` utilizo:

```js
let estilos = window.getComputedStyle(d, null);
let _display = estilos.getPropertyValue("display");
```

Si quiero saber el id de los divs (d) que tienen `display:block` por ejemplo, escribo:

```js
if(_display == "block"){console.log(d.id)}
```

A continuación viene un ejemplo:

```js
let lamismaclaseArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".lamismaclase"));

lamismaclaseArray.forEach(d=>{
  let estilos = window.getComputedStyle(d, null);
  let _display = estilos.getPropertyValue("display");
  //if(_display == "block"){console.log(d.id)}
  if(_display == "none"){console.log(d.id)}
})
```

```css
article{display:flex;}

.lamismaclase {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0.5em 0.25em;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
}

/* los pares tienen display none */
.lamismaclase:nth-of-type(odd){display:none}
```

```html
<article>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_0">0</div>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_1">1</div>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_2">2</div>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_3">3</div>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_4">4</div>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_5">5</div>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_6">6</div>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_7">7</div>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_8">8</div>
<div class="lamismaclase" id="_9">9</div>
<article>
```